# Writeback to Salesforce using Powerforms

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using Powerforms as an approach to get signatures using the DocuSign. What I want is to send some part of the data back to Salesforce from the PDF while the user signs it. I created custom fields on the PDF, related them to Salesforce, checked the writeback and allow sender to edit boxes but the data hasn't got back to SF yet. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you send from Salesforce, there is information passed to document (such as the SourceID and Source Object Type), that DocuSign Connect will attempt to match to a record to process a request to push the data back into Salesforce.

If you are using a PowerForm, you would have to pass along similiar data and setup DocuSign Connect correctly for it to relate the data back to a Salesforce record.

This is something that is doable with customization, but not functional out of the box.

Comment: I am passing the record ID in the powerform URL along with the other values. My URL looks like "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId = (the pf id) ..... other fields ..... +&EnvelopeField_DSFSSourceObjectId=(the record ID of Salesforce)